# jQuery to Align Decimals for a Bootstrap DataTable Column

Tags: jquery, alignment, decimal

For reference, please see this: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add() . My code is instantiating a table as:

```
var table =  $('#search_details_drilldowns').DataTable();
```

and then, in a loop, adding a bunch of rows. Cope snippet:

```
var unit_price = dynamicdata[0].toFixed(4);

//somehow modify the unit_price variable here?

table.row.add([unit_price]);
```

The value of unit_price can be like: `170.0000 or 14.2494 or 99999.0000` ; so always four decimals! The way the Datatable is displaying, the decimals are not aligned. I can't change the `<th>` column to right-align because I don't want to shift that.

So, what I am thinking of is to add spaces or somehow pad to the left of decimal points so long as the decimal points align. The values are for display only and so string is quite okay!

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found this library: https://github.com/ndp-software/align-column and used this:

```
 $('#search_details_drilldowns').alignColumn(8);
```

after `table.draw();` method and seems to be working.

HTH someone!

**Update** This answer will NOT work for me--this basically puts in two columns within each column of the DataTable and the data is not shown correctly. So the original Question still needs help! Thanks.

**Updated Answer Given Below!!**

The above Answer got me started into manipulating the CSS of individual cells. And here's how I fixed the problem!

Loaded a modified version of the Github library and then simply this in the For Loop--no splitting etc.

```
$cell.css('text-align', 'right');
$cell.css('padding-right', '20%');
```

I could do this without loading the extra library by calling some function in my main JS file but I thought to keep the code clean. Anyway, the new Answer works for me--although it is padding the `th` header as well which I will figure out to fix.

HTH!